# Searching within PHP multi dimensional array to return results within parent array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a function to search for a matching keyword in a multi dimensional array and return the corresponding name and path values.

```
$search_array = array(
  array(
    'keywords' => array('apple', 'orange'),
    'name' => 'Url One',
    'path' => 'http://www.urlone.com'
  ),
  array(
    'keywords' => array('bananna'),
    'name' => 'Url Two',
    'path' => 'http://www.urltwo.com'
  )
)
```

If there's a better way to structure this array to make it simpler the that would also be great, thanks

Comment: If it's just an array of "arrays that are actually just objects", then `foreach(){}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using array filter:

```
$matches = array_filter($search_array, function($array){
  return in_array('bananna', $array['keywords']);
});
```

Or using a foreach loop:

```
  $matches = [];
  foreach ($search_array as $key => $array) {
    if (in_array('apple', $array['keywords'])) {
      $matches[$key] = $search_array[$key];
    }
  }
```

Comment: This did the job, thanks